# Maximum CPU frequency on Boot

Tags: unity, cpufreq

How can I make the CPUs run at maximum frequency on startup/boot? Is there a script I can make or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually edit the `/etc/init.d/ondemand` file and change `echo -n ondemand > $CPUFREQ` to `echo -n performance > $CPUFREQ`.

The system uses `performance` during boot and then that script sets it to `ondemand` after boot.

**Edit:** You can also disable this script: `sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove`

Answer (score 0):

Add this somewhere for each cpu:

```
echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
```

Having that said, I'm not quite sure if that's a good idea. ;)